# How to create entity classes using database for all the existing tables?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having tables created by a DBA and I intend to have
entity classes for each table for further querying. Can any one suggest how to automatically create the entity classes using Eclipse?

Comment: Hibernate tools (part of JBoss Tools) can autogenerate entities from a database schema. Don't ask me how to use it though, I only managed to make it work through seam-gen which is part of the Seam 2 framework.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use JPA for persistence, you can use "JPA tools" provided by Eclipse to generate java entity class from tables.

Here is the [tutorial][1]

[1]: http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-create-java-classes-from-tables.html on my personal website.

Comment: Hi, would you please [edit] any answers linking to a personal website to include [a disclosure of affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)? As well, including some of the most important content from an external link is always a good idea to increase the value of answers.

Comment: I'll reword some of what miken32 said for clarity: the title of [the article they linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) is "How to not be a spammer". When linking to your own content you _must_ disclose that fact. This answer may be 7.5 years old, but your account appears to have been active as recently as this week. Please [edit] a disclosure in, and ideally also edit in the most important details from the blog post [so the answer is no longer of low quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627), or it may be flagged as spam and deleted.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate classes using [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html). There are two ways to generate these classes which is called as [Reverse Engineering and Code Generation](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.1.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/#refeng_codegen)[dead link] -

1. You can use Hibernate Tools Eclipse Plugin.
2. You can write Ant Script using Hibernate tools jar.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the **Telosys** code generator. It can help for this kind of job.

It allows to generate the Java (POJO) classes from any database
with the basic templates and you can also create your own
template (a Velocity file) to generate your DAO classes

For more information see [https://www.telosys.org](http://www.telosys.org)

Comment: See also the doc : https://doc.telosys.org/