# Is there an alternative tools to netbeans for generate jpa entity classes from database?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, entity

I have used for a project, Netbeans tool, to generate automatically the classes which contain the information of the database for each table. Is there a tool alternative for makes this operation?

Comment: You can use eclipse too, but it's actually done by eclipselink or hibernate tools (the most common). You can check answers to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140545/creating-entity-class-using-database-existing-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tudor,

there are several interesting tools to review.

1. [JBoss Forge](http://forge.jboss.org/)
2. [Appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home)
3. [Springfuse](http://www.springfuse.com/)
4. [Spring roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/)

You could search search Google for some tutorials concerning these tools.

Comment: Thanks you for help! I will see soon these tools.