# MySQL Workbench Model to Java Persistence Entity

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, jboss-tools

I am designing a database using MySQL Workbench. I've defined a bunch of tables and set up relationship via foreign keys. I am [preparing to forward engineer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-creating-a-model.html) this model to a database schema. Where do I go from there?

What I am looking to do is take the new database and create the Java entities that will correspond to said tables for use in a **SpringBoot** application. [I have seen a few posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140545/creating-entity-class-using-database-existing-table) that talk about different methods including Eclipse-based solutions that generate these artefacts, but many of these are older solutions and I'm not sure what the current "hot" tool is. Using **Spring Source Tool Suite**, I installed **JBoss Tools** which claims to do this via their [Hibernate Tools Reverse Engineering utility](http://hibernate.org/tools/), but I can't find any step-by-step documentation on how to proceed.

Since the project is in its infancy, I expect frequent changes to be made to the model and would like to consider a solution that can handle those types of updates as well.

Comment: Eclipse has inbuilt functionality: https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm. So does Netbeans: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.orm.doc/html/files/genJPAEntities.html.

Comment: About JBoss Tools - take a look here https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/videos/reveng_hibernatetools.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the utilities listed in the comments, there are a couple of other possibilities I want to mention:

1. [Maven Archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) - Maven-based templating toolkits that can generate projects according to different configurations
2. [JHipster](http://www.jhipster.tech/) - Yeoman-based templating toolkit that can generate opinionated best-practice Spring-Boot monolithic or microservice applications.

Number 2 is currently my go-to solution as it has a very active community and does a lot of "cool stuff".