# Convert tables into java entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have thousands of table in the database that needs to convert in hibernate java entities.What are the possible ways to do this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating entity class using database existing table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140545/creating-entity-class-using-database-existing-table)

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#refeng_codegen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Eclipse Dali Java Persistence Tools refer to this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm) on how to generate the entities.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple Java program to read the database meta data of the tables and column names in the tables.  It then could write out a Java class file per each table using the column names for the class variables.

A sample program that reads the DB meta information is here.  It could quickly be adapted to reading in the DB tables and writing out the Java classes.
[Sample Java DB Meta Data Program](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/program-search-for-given-field-name-in-all-database-tables-in-d)

A better set of examples for the generic JDBC Metadata API is [here](https://www.developer.com/java/data/discovering-database-metadata-with-the-jdbc-metadata-api.html)